Add column with quantile rank, within groups, using sample weight in R/dplyr
I have a data set have with the following structure:
have <- tibble::tibble(id = 1:30,  
                       state = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10), 
                       score = c(147, 735, 519, 458, 599, 628, 988, 787, 298, 612,
                                 319, 715, 248, 637, 239, 254, 601, 702, 902, 867,
                                 343, 535, 730, 518, 277, 612, 869, 865, 227, 641), 
                       weight = c(3.13, 1.46, 2.57, 4.39, 1.32, 3.81, 1.29, 1.58, 2.74, 4.13,
                                   1.43, 1.29, 1.81, 3.87, 3.10, 1.18, 4.15, 4.35, 3.35, 3.59,
                                   4.69, 3.38, 3.51, 3.35, 2.60, 1.99, 2.34, 4.60, 3.77, 1.31))

I would like to add a column with weighted terciles wterciles and another column with weighted quartiles wquartiles groups of score within each state incorporating sample weights weight.
The weight variable is a frequency expansion weight for computing point estimates. It is a variable needed to take into account because not all students who should take the test actually did it, so the institution responsible for the test calculated weights for students based on the attendance rate of each school and socioeconomic group. Therefore, the weight of 2 implies that this student should be counted as if he was 2 students when considering the state average.
I prefer {dplyr} syntax, but couldnt find a way of using weights in it. The dplyr::ntile() function does not handle weights.
Without weights it would be something like:
library(dplyr)

have %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
    mutate(
      wtercile = ntile(score, 3),
      wquartile = ntile(score, 4)) %>%
  ungroup()


https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13169/defining-quantiles-over-a-weighted-sample

Looks like the hutils package has a function for weighted ntiles: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/hutils/html/weighted_ntile.html

Weights is an unclear term and needs definition--there are many. How should the sample weights contribute?

I dont have a bachelor in statistics, but I guess it is a simple frequency expansion weight for point estimates, those kind that are usually used when one have sample data, as I thought it could be deduced from the data sample I provided. Do you know those kind of weights you can simply "turn on" in SPSS? Which kind of weights there are?
